# Как реализовать подтверждение номера телефона через смс

Tags: android, sms

Как реализовать подтверждение номера телефона через смс в собственном андроид приложении. То есть я хочу сделать, что при регистрации указывается номер мобильного телефона, и для завершения регистрации нужно указать код из смс.

Подскажите, как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: Найти подходящего провайдера и воспользоваться их API. Реализация на ваших плечах.

Пример http://nexmo.com

SDK: https://github.com/Nexmo/verify-android-sdk

Comment: А попроще нету ничего?

Answer (score 4):

Заключаешь договор с SMS-шлюзом. Например, [sms.ru](http://sms.ru) или [smsc.ru](http://smsc.ru) (Не реклама!)
У них есть API, к которому можно обращаться post-запросом.

1.Формируешь на стороне сервера уникальный код

2.Передаешь его в api с указанием номера клиента.
Примерно так:

```
curl "http://IpOfService/sendsms.cgi?http_username=YouUsername&http_password=YourPassword&phone_list=CustomerNumber&fromphone=NameOfYouService&message=$Нужные$Данные"
```

3.Клиент получил код подтверждения.

4.Проверяешь код на соответствие отправленному.

P.S. Проще вообще некуда. Хоть вручную по запросу дергать ссылку на API.

Answer (score 0):

Для этой задачи вам не обойтись без сторонних сервисов. Быстрый поиск в гугле выдает много результатов. Например, https://checkmobi.com/